# MSSQL: [newbie corner] insert data into row based on matched criteria

Tags: sql-server

I've been digging through posts here and trying to update a column based on some criteria. The basic flow is this:

**Before:**

```
firstname     | firstname_match  |
-----------------------------------
Bob and Mary  | [NULL] 
James         | [NULL]
```

Then:

```
UPDATE table.name
SET firstname_match = '1'
WHERE firstname LIKE "% and %";
```

**After:**

```
firstname     | firstname_match  |
-----------------------------------
Bob and Mary  | 1
James         | [NULL]
```

I'm new to SQL as a whole so I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but when I run the above command, I get an error stating "Invalid column name '% and %'. It looks like it's trying to force me to compare one column to another, but that's not what I want to do. I want to search based on a LIKE and then update a different column so I can count the total number of matches later on (I have some 95 different criteria to check against and want to pull a limited result set favoring the rows that meet the most individual criteria simultaneously, which is a whole 'nother thing).

Thoughts? Thanks in advance! I'm reasonably sure this is a matter of not having the vocabulary yet to search for what I want...

Comment: You need single quote not double. (i.e. `WHERE firstname LIKE '% and %'`)

Comment: @YogeshSharma hit the nail on the head.  That is your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel a little silly on something that simple. lol

Comment: For a beginner, the important lesson to learn here is that SQL Server uses single quotes to indicate a literal string, and double quotes to indicate a column name or alias.

Comment: Tagging onto @TabAlleman comment, [QUOTED_IDENTIFER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) deserves a quick read since literals can be done with double quotes, but this isn't the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET firstname_match = '1'
WHERE firstname LIKE '% and %';
```